# Javascript : Remove special symbols from string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to remove this special symbol `§` from a text but JavaScript won't seem to recognize it. So it wouldn't remove it at all. The only solution I've tried is this, with no luck:

```
var x = "Hello § How Are You §";
x = x.replace('§', '');
console.log(x);
```

And this is the console output I receive:

`Hello § How Are You §`

But when I remove any other regular character that can be found on a keyboard, it works normally. For example:

```
var x = "Hello § How Are You §";
x = x.replace('H', '');
console.log(x);
```

And this is the console output I receive:

`ello § How Are You §`

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: use `var y = x.replace('§', '');` and then log `y`. If you want to remove all occurances use `var y = x.replace(/§/g, '');`

Comment: Still no luck, I've tried both and no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable in JavaScript.  You need to assign the replacement to `x`.  In addition, if you want to remove all `§` symbols, you may use a global regex replacement.

```js
var x = "Hello § How Are You §";
x = x.replace(/§/g, '');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: That was a mistake while typing, I've already done that with still the same issue

Comment: @pikoloy871 The demo in my answer is working.  You must have some other problem.

Comment: Okay, I've tried this again and it seems to work? Any way on how I concatenate with a regular letter/number and remove it after? for example: `§a` becomes ''. So `Hell§o` would be `Hell`? I've tried using '+' but then it just doesn't remove the symbol or the letter/number after it

Comment: For a single trailing letter or number, replace on `/§\w/`.  For multiple following word characters, use `/§\w+/`

Comment: I've tried `x = x.replace(/§\w/, '');` But got no luck, and didn't replace anything, did i do it wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I tried what you told me to do but it didn't remove the symbol or the single trailing character afterwards

Comment: Use: `x = x.replace(/§\w+/g, '');`

Comment: `x = x.replace(/§./g, '')` worked for me to replace a single following character.